# SharePoint List Calculated Field updates from using Edit All and Saving (even if field didn't change)

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, sharepoint-list

I have a `Yes/No` field.  If yes, a `Calculated` field puts the current time.

```
=IF(Resolved,TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"),"Unresolved")
```

The issue I have is if I click a list item that is set to resolved, then click "Edit All", when I click save, the `ResolvedDate` field is re-calculated.  This happens if I update any field or do not update any field.

Can I compare the pre-save value to the new value and if equal, don't output anything?

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

The calculated column is doing exactly what your formula wants it to do. 
You want to have the formula use the current timestamp if your column is true. When you use "Edit all" your calculated columns get recalculated.

You can only avoid this by disabling "Edit all" in advanced list settings. Then your users are forced to use "Edit item" to edit every single item. That will not affect all other elements.

There is no "calculated-column-formula" to avoid this behavior.

Comment: I'm looking at the Advanced Settings and I don't see where to disable the Edit All.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your requirement, if you use the calculated column, you will meet the re-calculated issue.

As a workaround, you can use a date time field or a single line of text field to instead of the calculated field. And then create a workflow for list to set the current date to the field.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works. If you want to prevent it you need to do the calculation differently. I had similar request in past and instead of the calculated column I have used Infopath form and I made the calculation there. This way calculation only happens if you open the form (and with rules you can limit it further)